# Translate HTML files to another language

Tags: html, transactions, multilingual

I have a website in English which I want to translate to Spanish. Is there a fast way of doing this with keeping the HTML tags(`<strong>,<span>`) in tact?. I know I can just copy the parsed TEXT into a translator but this will take a lot of time.

I plan to rewrite all the needed parts to provide a high translation quality, but I dont want to translate it from scratch.

Disclaimer: A similar question has been asked but it didnt get a real answer

**UPDATE**

[Old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839591/translate-html-files-to-another-language?rq=1)

I posted a new question because the previous question is different in the sense that the owner poster accepted that translation by scratch as an answer and that is what I'm trying to avoid.

Google Translate would be fine, but it doesnt support translating batch files, and API is paid. I'm looking for a free solution.

I want to translate a website with ~100 articles so I was looking for a automatic translation as a way to begin.

I hope the question is clearer now.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Not enough info. Quite possibly off-topic. You should identify the previous question. And you should not post a duplicate just because an old question “didnt get a real answer”; try to contribute to improving the old question (or its answers).

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela question updated

Comment: The old question has the *correct* answer as the accepted answer. Now that you have specified that you are looking for automatic translation, the question *is* a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what translator you are using but Google Translate will not translate anything that are inside these `< >`

`<strong>I'm Awesome</strong>` will be `<strong> Soy impresionante </ strong>`

Answer (score 0):

Google translate is your best bet, it won't translate any HTML within < and > tags

Comment: Using Google Translate will surely not give “high translation quality”.